# AngularJS: UI Router nested routes with un-nested views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular ui-router in my project and I'm running into an issue..

I want to have the following routes: `/home`, `/home/:collection`, `/home/:collection/:item`

So this is my current code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
    })

    .state('home.collection', {
        url: '/:collection',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.collection.html',
        controller: 'CollectionCtrl'
    })

    .state('home.collection.item', {
        url: '/:item',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.item.html',
        controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Is there a way to use the following structure with ui-router (this represents the `home` view):

```
<div id="hero" class="container">
    <h1>Welcome, select an item below</h1>
</div>

<div id="collection-selector">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="collection in collections">
            <a href="#/{{collection}}">{{collection}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- collection view -->
    <div ui-view id="item-selector"></div>
</div>

<div id="item-details" ng-if="item.selected">
    <!-- item view -->
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

So the first view would represent `/home/:collection` and then if the user navigates to `/home/collection/:item` then I can use some logic to have the item detail pane appear below it. I've only managed to get it working by nesting the `item` view inside the `collection` view, which is obviously expected behavior, but I was hoping there would be a work around to unnest the views, but have the routing nested.

Right now, if I put my collection picker inside the `ui-view` then it won't show the picker on the `/home` route, which is an issue. And the styles associated with the collection picker and the detail view is very different and disconnected so I don't want to have to nest them if I can avoid it.

I might be taking the completely wrong approach to this problem and if I am please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found the answer, if you use the `views` property in the router, you can target which view will pickup the view... as butchered as that sounds... here is the code:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
})

.state('home.collection', {
    url: '/:collection',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.collection.html',
    controller: 'CollectionCtrl'
})

.state('home.collection.item', {
    url: '/:item',
    views: {
         "item@home" : {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.item.html',
            controller: 'ItemCtrl'
         }
     }
});
```

And then the additiona HTML which will appear in the `views/home.html` page:

```
<div ui-view="item" />
```

So when I navigate to `/home/:collection/:item` the `item` will appear in the view that is placed on the `views/home.html`